# Reduce number of repeating SUM functions in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to reduce the number of SUM functions in my query?

```
    SELECT P_NAME "Product name", (SUM(case when PR = 1 then QUANTITY end) -
SUM(case when PR = 2 then QUANTITY end)) "End balance",
CAST((SUM(case when PR = 1 then QUANTITY*PRICE end) - SUM(case when PR = 2 then
QUANTITY*PRICE end)) as decimal(13,2)) "End balance" FROM RPOD, DMS, DMZ
WHERE RPOD.KTOV=DMS.KTOV AND DMZ.NDM=DMS.DMZ_FK
GROUP BY P_NAME
ORDER BY P_NAME;
```

Comment: i think reducing sum's will change your logic,only thing i will change is use aliases and use modern style joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them:

```
SELECT P_NAME as "Product name",
       SUM(case when PR = 1 then QUANTITY
                when PR = 2 then - QUANTITY
           end) as "End balance",
       SUM(case when PR = 1 then QUANTITY * PRICE
                when PR = 2 then - QUANTITY * PRICE
           end) as "End balance/price",
FROM RPOD JOIN
     DMS
     ON RPOD.KTOV = DMS.KTOV JOIN
     DMZ
     ON DMZ.NDM = DMS.DMZ_FK
GROUP BY P_NAME
ORDER BY P_NAME;
```

Much more important aesthetics about `SUM()`s is learning to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `JOIN` clause.  Also, you should not give two columns in the result set the same name.